# How to solve ATKKBService.exe error?

Tags: windows-xp

I get this error when starting up my PC. And there are an option whether I want to debug it or not (using visual studio because I have it installed on my PC) and I choose No.

I search google and found that this may be caused by ASUS's something, I don't really understand.

Anyone had this kind of error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATKKBService.exe is common on ASUS laptops. I am unsure of its purpose, but on my system it seems to do something involving hotkeys (and is one of about a billion separate programs that work with the hotkeys).  If you have an ASUS computer, go to http://support.asus.com/, select downloads, then choose your computer from the drop-down lists. Download anything that mentions ATK, Keyboard, or Filter Driver.  Then uninstall anything with those words from your add/remove programs menu, and re-install them from the files you downloaded. If you do not have an ASUS computer, just uninstall anything with "ATK" in it from the add/remove programs menu.